# Replace special character in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

For one of my daily manually find and replace task I want to create a powershell script to find and replace some network location and replace with new one.

Like :-

To find : `\\Test\test`

Replace with `\\Test1\Test1`

I am able to replace text without any special characters but for above I am getting regular expression error.

And also after replacing above string I want to save result in a text file which logs records of files which have been updated.

Comment: show the expression that causes the problem. The only regex special character you have in there is `\ `, to match the backslash literally in a regex, just escape it `\\ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your example in the comment, just needs an Add-Content snip to complete it. This is how I would do it.

```
$c = '\\filedep\iservershare\DCSVWA'
$c = $c -replace [regex]::Escape('\\filedep\iservershare\DCSVWA'),('\\EGSISFS01\VolksWagon\DCSVWA')
Add-Content C:\Output.txt $c
```

I've run it twice and the file resulted in.

```
\\EGSISFS01\VolksWagon\DCSVWA
\\EGSISFS01\VolksWagon\DCSVWA
```

Comment: Thanks K, But it is not giving me desired output.
I want list of all the files with location which has been updated due to above script..

Comment: what is the name of the variable of each file your are looping through, or are you inside pipeline at that point >>($_)<<.  Either way, just need replace my $c in add-content with that $var, if in pipeline I assume, `Add-Content C:\Output.txt $_` , otherwise if named variable, same thing except be sure the add-content occurs inside your loop.